# Is Natspec still used?

Tags: solidity, natspec

Is the natural specification format a real standard, or a mostly unused tool?
I wonder if it is worth natspeccing my programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely optional and up to the individual dev.  That said, the solc compiler enforces the natspec.  It will throw a fit if a parameter isn't documented but should be or is documented but not in the function.

For instance, I just got this:

```
Error: Documented parameter "_sender" not found in the parameter list of the function.
```

In this case, because I documented a parameter that wasn't in the function.